# Quasi mathematical objects

Tags: elementary-number-theory, philosophy

I was looking on this post http://www.songho.ca/math/euler/euler.html and I came to the comment that says "i is not a number at all. It is an ill-formed concept. There is a vast difference between a magnitude and a number. The objects you think of as" complex numbers" are not numbers of any kind whatsoever. They are quasi-mathematical objects."

by wiki a mathematical object is "In mathematical practice, an object is anything that has been (or could be) formally defined, and with which one may do deductive reasoning and mathematical proofs."

I tried to search over internet about the term "**quasi mathematical object**" but it just says about literal meaning. 
I wonder what are they? or there is no such term exist in mathematics?

---

EDIT: I am not agree with the comment (that i is not a number) but I am stuck with the term "Quasi mathematical object" so I even understand the meaning of it but is there such a thing exist? I am more looking for example if the term "quasi mathematical object" exist. If not then I should delete this post. Thanks for taking your time.

Comment: I believe you are attributing more weight to a comment than it should have. I interpret "quasi-mathematical" as "resembling being mathematical but not mathematical". It comes over as: real number good number, complex number bad number. I believe that comment is plain wrong when qualifying complex numbers not as mathematical.

Comment: It's very simple: the comment is incorrect. Don't believe everything you read on the internet. The word "quasi-mathematical object" doesn't have any technical meaning more than the word "flibble-geep", which I just made up. Incidentally, John Gabriel is a well-known crackpot who doesn't understand calculus.

Comment: The comment you are pointing to is just a very bad piece of writing, and even worse from the point of mathematical point of view. It operates with undefined concepts ("magnitude", "number", "quasi-mathematical object"). It gives no proof or reference for its claim which is obviously in contradiction to a vast majority of mathematitians. I wouldn't concern myself with such comments.

Comment: I am not looking for if the comment was right or wrong. I am looking for if there is any quasi mathematical object exist?

Comment: Mathematicians tend to use different terms in place of "quasi mathematical object".  For example, when the Fields medalist Alain Connes wanted to describe infinitesimals, he relied on a time-honored tradition and called them "chimeras".

Comment: Incidentally, you are the only one who is automatically notified by means of a red flag of the existence of a comment or answer to your question. If you want other users to notice your comments, you should write something like @5xum

Answer (score 2):

That comment looks to be from someone who has not studied mathematics rigorously and could well be a physicist or engineer etc who uses number systems but doesn't study them specifically (controversial comment but hear me out).

When he says i is not a number he is quite correct if he restricts himself to the 'usual' number systems of $\mathbb{N},~ \mathbb{Z},~ \mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$. And it appears that this is exactly what he is doing. However, a number system is more generally a set with operations between the elements which form a group, a ring or some other algebraic object. It is precisely as one of these algebraic objects that we define the complex numbers, they exist abstractly without needing any geometric interpretation. This is I think where the writer of that comment has misunderstood. Complex numbers aren't some convenient addition to the reals that we glued on to make pretty shapes, it is a fundamental extension of the real numbers that exists very naturally and we need in order for instance to have well defined roots of polynomial equations.

In conclusion I don't think that the writer of that comment knows what they are talking about, complex numbers are fundamental, hugely important, natural and elegant and are in no way ill-formed whatsoever.

Reply to question edit:

I have never ever heard the term 'quasi-mathematical object', I believe that it was made up by the person posting the comment.

Comment: will you please refer the edit.